# Как обновить datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Пытаюсь выполнить sql команду и обновить datagrid, как это можно сделать?

```csharp
public static void SRCH()
{
    while (Form1.connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Form1.connection.Open();
    }
    SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE FirstName  LIKE N'" + addClients.addcl + "'", Form1.connection);
    //  sql.ExecuteReader();
    sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //add.clientsTableAdapter.Fill(add.database1DataSet.Clients);
    //add.clientsTableAdapter.Update()
    addClients.adcl.Abort();
}
```

Comment: WPF? Загрузите ответ в коллекцию, например `List` или `ObservableCollection`, и присвойте ее свойству `ItemsSource` у `DataGrid`.

Comment: WF. можно пример ? с list

Comment: В xaml `<DataGrid x:Name="MyDG">`. Потом в коде `MyDG.ItemsSource = myList`. Как поместить при этом данные в `myList` из ответа БД, вам виднее.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dw = new DataTable("Clients");
SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE FirstName  LIKE N'" + addClients.addcl + "'", Form1.connection);
db.Fill(dw);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dw.DefaultView;
```

Иногда ещё помогает:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dw.DefaultView;
```